# NetBeans profiler "stops working" after 50 thread limit?

Tags: multithreading, netbeans, hadoop, profiler

I'm trying to use the NetBeans 7.1 profiler to profile a program which runs a series of hadoop tasks (local, single-process), but each task is started in a separate thread.

I've set my root methods to be the map and reduce methods of the Mapper and Reducer which I'm using, but it seems like after thread 50, the netbeans profiler simply stops profiling.  It doesn't recognize when the root methods are called again.

The live results stop and snapshot I get at the end only seems to contain data from the first couple tasks.

Does anyone know why this happens or how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.  There's a "Limit Number of Profiled Threads" setting under advanced settings which is by default set to 32