# how to find out the amount of memory used

Tags: c++, c, profiling, heap-memory, dynamic-allocation

I am trying out a C/C++ program, I want to know how much memory i am using due to heap and some other data structures. So how can I find out the amount of memory used by my various data structures?

I think that malloc operator should be overridden but I am not sure about the same.
I am working on Linux and on Netbeans 7.1.

Comment: also see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690800/how-to-profile-memory-usage)

Comment: @hamed Thanks..+1 to ur comment. Also since I am working on netbeans...is there anyway by which netbeans may help me with...i am a complete novice at this..thats why asking..also thanks helping. This community really rocks because of people like u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use memory profilers for c++ like Valgrind as recommended in similar questions.
see [this](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)

For netbeans IDE look at [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/profiling-tools.html).

Comment: Thanks again for the help...the link u provided if for netbeans 6.9 but I am working with Netbeans 7.1....can you please please provide some good link for netbeans 7.1...thanks again

Comment: @RoseBEck: someone is preventing you from using a shell? Open it and run valgrind, it's by far the easiest way to do it

Comment: @akappa actually I am running a huge C++ project containing several files and folders..so I am a bit worried that will Valgrind work for my huge project...i know it works well for single files..but is it true that it works for huge project...also thanks for being kind and replying

Comment: Release Notes of **7.1.2** say: 
_The C/C++ Profiling Tools were removed from the standard distribution of the IDE._ and I think that you should try @akappa solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121344/netbeans-profiler-stops-working-after-50-thread-limit This guy seams to be using the netbeans 7.1 profiler...but i don't understand how? Can someone help

Comment: @hamed I know this is a foolish question but does Valgrind work for large projects containing several files and folders

Comment: @RoseBEck: valgrind runs executable, so it doesn't care how many files and directories your project is composed of.

Comment: @hamed The ouput on the linux terminal scrolls out fast and disappears when using ms_print...is theresome why by which I may see the entire output...before it disappears

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hand-made memory profiling then you need to overload `operator new` and/or `malloc()` function. Though `malloc()` can be overloaded easily, but you need to use macro tricks.

Advantage of using and overloading `operator new` is that, it's easier, elegant and you can evaluate each type of `struct`/`class` separately.